# How to block negative numbers on h:inputText with JSF

Tags: validation, jsf-2, message, negative-number

I´m using jsf to build a form, and I have this kind of inputtext:

```
<div class="profile-info-row">
    <div class="profile-info-name">Promoção:</div>
    <div class="profile-info-value">
        <span class="input-icon input-icon-right">
            <h:inputText id="promocao" class="input-medium"
                value="#{itemController.itemPreco.promocao}"
                converterMessage="Valor inválido. (Ex.: 0.00)">
                <f:convertNumber locale="pt"/>
                <f:ajax event="change" render="promocaoMensagem"/>
            </h:inputText>
        </span>
        <div class="help-inline mensagemErro">
            <h:message for="promocao" id="promocaoMensagem"/>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

and I have to block negative numbers and give a message to user inline that number is forbidden, how is working when the user types a invalid number on input..

Does someone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`<f:validateLongRange>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/validateLongRange.html) with a `minimum` of `0`.

```
<h:inputText ...>
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="0" />
</h:inputText>
```

The default validation message is:

> Validation Error: Value is less than allowable minimum of '0'

Any custom validation message can be set via `validatorMessage` the same way as you did for `converterMessage`.

Comment: And you can override the message by adding the key javax.faces.validator.LongRangeValidator.MINIMUM in your properties file!